# Get all matricies recursively in specific range

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to calculate and save to file every N x N matrix combination in C, where every element is in specific range, for example:

```
N = 3
Range: 0,1

1st iteration
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

2nd iteration
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 1

3rd iteration
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 0

4th iteration
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 1

5th iteration
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0

etc.
```

I've figured out that the most reasonable solution is to do it recursivly to avoid a lot of nested for-loops for bigger Ns, so here's my function:

```c
void get_all_matricies(int** matrix, int size, int min, int max, FILE* file, int i, int j) {
    if(i == size) return;

    for(int k = min; k <= max; k++) {
        matrix[i][j] = k;
        if(j < size-1) {
            get_all_matricies(matrix, size, min, max, file, i, j+1);
        } else {
            get_all_matricies(matrix, size, min, max, file, i+1, 0);
            save_matrix(matrix, size, file);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work just fine, but there's a problem, where sometimes (when bottom row gets "filled" to be exact) I get the same matrix twice, for example:

```
N = 3
Range: 0,1

nth iteration
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
1 1 0 

nth+1 iteration
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
1 1 1 

nth+2 iteration
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
1 1 1 

nth+3 iteration
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 0
```

Is there any issue why this happens?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I've tried the else-if thing, but still, can't get it working properly. Analzying it step by step is not a bad idea though.

Comment: This is the same problem as permuting a 1-dimensional array of `N*N` through every value, and might be easier to reason about and code. i.e. the fact that it a square matrix is irrelevant. It's just a bunch of numbers to permute.

Comment: Move your `save_matrix` call to the early-out part. You only want to output the matrix after recursion has reached the end of the matrix. _i.e._ `if(i == size) { save_matrix(matrix, size, file); return; }`

Comment: That's right. Works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simple case of iterating over a set: Enumerating, i.e. counting. You do not need recursion for counting**.

So, if your question happens to be about iterating over all possible matrices in a logically simple way, let me explain the simple iteration by enumeration (counting). If your question is specifically on implementing the iteration by recursion, this is not an answer to your question.

For an `N×N` matrix, you have `N*N` places in the matrix to fill with any of the `B` values from the range. This is equivalent to an `N*N` digit number in base `B`, with each digit being one value from the range (or being 1:1 mapped to one value from the range, if your range happens to not be in the form `0, 1, 2, ..., B-1`). To enumerate all `N*N` digit base `B` numbers, you just need to count from `0` to `B^(N*N)-1`.

In your example, every digit is either `0` or `1`, so you just need to count from `0` to `2^(N*N)-1` and then display the counter in base `2`, while arranging the `N*N` base `2` digits in the form of an `N×N` matrix. This will require `N*N` bit shifts and `&1` masks per counter value, no division instructions.

If your range was `0, 1, 2` or `-1, 0, +1`, there are `3` values in the range, and you would need to count from `0` to `3^[N*N)-1`, and then display the counter in base `3`, while mapping the base `3` digits `0, 1, 2` to `-1, 0, +1` for the second example. This will require `N*N` divisions by `3` per counter value (`divmod` operations to be exact, as you need both the quotient and the remainder).

And so on.

If you happen to be worried about performance: Counting from `0` to a positive integer in a loop is a very inexpensive operation, and you can replace the divisions required to convert the counter value into a sequence of digits in base `B` in the inner loop by multiplications or bit shifts, and it is possible your compiler already does that. While bit shifts are really inexpensive, avoiding the divisions might be a reason to go back to recursion. It is also reasonable to assume the operations you plan to do on the matrices will require in the order of or more CPU cycles than the enumeration loop and the conversion loop for `N*N` base `B` digits require.

Regarding memory performance, if you do not mind the sequence in which the matrices are issued, the enumeration function does not even need storage for a complete matrix, it can just spit out the matrix coefficients one by one. If you want a special order for the enumerated matrices, reversing the digits might be helpful, and that requires storage for the coefficients of a single `N×N` matrix.

Note: If the cardinality `B` of your range set is not a power of 2, you will need to divide with `N*N` `divmod` operations per iteration to display the counter in base `B`. In a recursive approach, each level of recursion will iterate over one digit, and those digits will need to be stored separately from the call stacks as you cannot iterate over the call stack in C. So as those digits are already stored separately (probably in a simple array), printing the digits will not require divisions.

** There is no need for recursion here if you have a `for` loop or an iterator available for counting. You would only need recursion in a language which implements counting and iterating by recursion, e.g. Erlang or XSLT (other such languages exist).

Comment: That's a very well-explained approach, I didn't think about it in this way before. Indeed a nice way.